# rtk query is not a function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I am encountering a problem while attempting to perform a GET request using RTK Query. The current configuration I have is as follows:

api.ts
// Basic api setup

```
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from "@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react";

export const api = createApi({
 
reducerPath: "feedApi",
 
baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: "/api" }),
 
tagTypes: [],
 
endpoints: () => ({}),
});
```

feedApi.ts
// my endpoints

```
import { api } from "./api/api";

type feedProps = {
type: [];
items: {
    type: string;
    format: string;
};
title: string;
};

export const feedApi = api.injectEndpoints({
endpoints: (build) => ({
    imageFeed: build.query<feedProps, string>({
        query: (prompt) => ({
            url: `http://localhost:3001/image-feed?prompt=${prompt}`,
        }),
    }),
    videoFeed: build.query<feedProps, string>({
        query: (prompt) => ({
            url: `http://localhost:3001/video-feed?prompt=${prompt}`,
        }),
    }),
   }),
});

export const { useImageFeedQuery, useVideoFeedQuery } = feedApi;
```

form.tsx

```
import { useEffect, FC } from "react";
import { Controller, useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import Textarea from "../Textarea/Textarea";
import { yupResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/yup";

import SubmitIcon from "../../assets/icons/right-arrow.svg";
import { StyledFormContainer } from "./Form.styled";
import { validationSchema } from "./validationSchema";
import VideoPlayer from "../VideoPlayer/VideoPlayer";
import Card from "../Card";
import { image, videoJsOptions } from "../../features/Chat/constants";

import { useImageFeedQuery} from "../../app/services/feedApi";


interface FormProps {
formType: string | undefined | null;
}

type FormValues = {
prompt: string;
};

const Form: FC<FormProps> = ({ formType }) => {
const [imageFeed, { isSuccess }] = useImageFeedQuery();

const {
    handleSubmit,
    control,
    reset,
    formState: { errors },
} = useForm<FormValues>({
    defaultValues: {
        prompt: "",
    },
    mode: "onBlur",
    resolver: yupResolver(validationSchema),
});

useEffect(() => reset(), [reset, formType]);

const onSubmit = ({ prompt }: FormValues) => {
    console.log(prompt);
    imageFeed(prompt);
};

return (
    <StyledFormContainer>
        <div className="media-container">
            {formType === "video" ? (
                <VideoPlayer options={videoJsOptions} />
            ) : (
                <div className="images-feed">
                    <Card url={image} />
                </div>
            )}
        </div>
        <form
            onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
            className={`${errors.prompt?.message ? "error" : ""}`}
        >
            <div className="caption-container">
                <Controller
                    control={control}
                    name="prompt"
                    render={({ field: { onChange, value } }) => (
                        <Textarea
                            onChange={onChange}
                            value={value}
                            error={errors.prompt?.message}
                        />
                    )}
                />
            </div>
             
            <div className="btn-container">
                <button>
                    <img
                        src={SubmitIcon}
                        width={20}
                        height={20}
                        alt="submit"
                    />
                </button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </StyledFormContainer>
   );
};

export default Form;
```

I am observing the following errors in the browser:

1. Uncaught TypeError: useImageFeedQuery is not a function or its return value is not iterable.

Do you have any suggestions on how I should tackle this?

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```js
const { data, isSuccess } = useImageFeedQuery();
const imageFeed = data
```

`use*Query` returns only an object. The array notation only exists for `use*LazyQuery`.

Comment: The imageFeed acts as a function that allows me to invoke the hook within onSubmit. Do you have any suggestions for how I should tackle this ?

Comment: use `useImageFeedLazyQuery` instead.

Comment: Hey phry, thanks for your answers. The useImageFeedQuery is auto generated from rtk query. The useImageFeedLazyQuery is not provided. Can you explain me what do you meant?

Comment: @GregorisBaxtsevanos Both of these hooks are autogenerated by RTK Query unless you explicitly disabled the generation of lazy queries. Please look again.